# Pig INDEXOF function with '\'

Tags: apache-pig

I want to get the index of `\` from a file

It enters into a state (with `>>` prompt) from which I have to do Ctrl+z to come out of pig and then have to explicitly go to pig again

The code I use is

```
grunt> A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (username:chararray, address:char array);

grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE INDEXOF(username, '\', 0);

>>
```

But when I try the same thing for other chars, I get the output
The code being

```
grunt> A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (username:chararray, address:char array);

grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE INDEXOF(username, 'a', 0);

grunt> DUMP B;
```

Output:

```
-1
-1
.
.
.
```

It even works for chars `/`, `<`, `>` and most of the chars I have tried. Just not for `\`
Please suggest a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is a *[metacharacter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter)* in Java strings. It allows you to specify characters like tab (`\t`), newline (`\n`), and more. It also allows you to embed a single quote, so that it doesn't terminate the string. For example, to make a string consisting of a single quote in Pig, you would use `'\''`.  Hence, in your example, you are "escaping" the single quote, and Pig is trying to interpret everything after it as part of your string.

Now, because you might want to have a backslash in a string, you can also escape it. Try using `'\\'` and you should get the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using '\' too, used the unicode character for \
None of them worked.

I suggest using the function REGEX

Answer (score 0):

In Pig 0.13.0 
Even if we try '\\' it goes into listening mode
e.g.

> grunt> A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS
>   (username:chararray, address:char array);
>
> grunt>`--` This will go into listening mode
>
> grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE INDEXOF(username, '\\', 0);
>
> `>>`

So tried using unicode character '\u005C' instead of '\' symbol for getting index

> grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE INDEXOF(username, '\\u005C', 0);
>   This is also not working.

So tried another alternative from bit of hack.

> grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE INDEXOF(username, TRIM('\\ '), 0);

This is working and the previous issue of going into listening mode as '\\' is escaping the ' which makes it to go into listening mode thus using space and trim it got resolved.